Is the money in a minor's s saving account part of his wealth and therefore counted in his nisab?
My parents have put money in a child's saving account for me, but obviously I don't have access to yet until I turn 18 years old. So should I count it among my wealth. I'm worried about this since if I include the money it fulfills the Nisab and makes Zakat obligatory upon me, and it would have been for a few years.
